# SwiftUI: "Swift Frontend" memory leak

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, memory-leaks, xcode13

When rendering previews in XCode, occasionally a process called ***"swift-frontend"*** will show up in Activity Monitor, and use up all available memory and make my computer freeze and be unusable

Any ideas to what this process might be, and how it's triggered?

*Running XCode 13.1, on a MacBook Air with macOS Montery*

Comment: “Despite this being impossible“ it’s not. Mac OS supports paging. Or perhaps you’re just looking at the virtual memory allocated to the process, which has no bearing on the amount of memory actually used. It’s possible to have terabytes of VM allocated to a process, without a single physical byte used

Comment: Xcode 13 has many strange bugs and this seems to be one of them. I guess the only option you have it to wait for an Xcode version that solves that problem (and introduces not to many new issues.)